# Rails does not load page for the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I press for example a link it redirects to this URL, but does not open full. It loads(loader gif moves). But when I press reload again - it loads. What is a problem? Can anyone saw such thing? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Open Developer Tools in your browser and look at section of loading resources. For example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) is Network Monitor of Firefox. It help you to investigate reason of problem. Probably some third-party resources isn't loading.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @maxd, use the Network Monitor in Firefox or Chrome Dev Tools to investigate further.

It sounds like the issue could be caused by the turbolinks gem conflicting with jQuery. Try removing turbolinks and restarting your local server to see if the problem persists.

Remove the following lines:

Gemfile: `gem 'turbolinks'` 
application.js:  `//= require turbolinks` 
application.html.erb: `"data-turbolinks-track => true"`

Alternatively, if you want to use turbolinks, you can implement the [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem into your app.